# Is the Debye Length Meaningful for a Pure Ion Plasma

Tags: electrostatics, simulations, plasma-physics, debye-length

I'm current working in a research area that is adapting techniques from plasma simulation to simulation spacecraft electric propulsion systems that are not neutralized. Essentially they are pure ion beams of either positive or negative ions.

A significant amount of guidance for the original electrostatic techniques requires configuring simulation resolution around the Debye length of the plasma. From my cursory understanding the Debye length represents shielding by mobile charge carriers which requires charge carriers of both polarities. As I have only positive ions, it is my understanding that there is no shielding and all particles interact with all others - analogous to N-Body gravitational interactions.

Is there a meaningful interpretation of the Debye length for these conditions or is any calculated length value arbitrary?

Comment: How do you propose to keep electrons from the environment from neutralizing your ion flows?

Comment: On long timescales in real applications we don't, the background electrons will interact the with the positive plume though I am not familiar with what background densities are present in deep space/experimental vacuum chamber conditions. This also include negative operation where we emit negative molecular ions that would have to be neutralized by positive free ions.

If we are assuming an ideal vacuum, is there a meaningful interpretation of the ion debye length?

Comment: An ionized gas comprised entirely of ions is not a plasma.  The Debye length is meaningful when there is some sort of electrostatic shielding occurring causing there to be an equal number of positive and negative charges, thus resulting in a quasi-neutral gas inside a Debye sphere.  So if there are only ions, this fails.  If you are thinking about injecting extra ions into an already quasi-neutral plasma, that's completely different than your title...

Comment: Correct this is more analogous to an ion beam in the absence of any other particles - is there any characteristic length scale that can be derived for these conditions or is there none?

Comment: The inertial length and thermal gyroradii are probably relevant for several things, but it's difficult to know without more context.  Generally, ion beams emitted from spacecraft by propulsion or intentional release produce things like ion Bernstein waves and other modes through different types of beam or streaming instabilities.